# Accumulator value always getting 0

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Always getting Accumulator value as 0.

```
package com.fast.processing.data

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

object AccumulatorExample {
      def main(args:Array[String]){

      val spark = new SparkConf().setAppName("AccumulatorExample").setMaster("local")
      val sc = new SparkContext(spark)

      val data = sc.textFile("C:\\Users\\SportsData.txt")
      val badLines = sc.accumulator(0,"badLines");

      val datVal = data.foreach(line =>(line.split(",").map{x=>{
                  if(x(0).toInt < 0) badLines +=1
                }  
              }

      ) )
      println("Val of bad lines is:::"+badLines)
  }
```

}

Below is the data and I am expecting accumulator value as 4, since every row is having first value less than 0.

```
-1,10,India,2019,01-01-2019,Cricket,5,6,7,18 
-2,11,Japan,2018,01-01-2018,Football,6,6,6,18
-3,12,China,2017,01-01-2017,Tennis,7,7,7,21 
-4,13,India,2018,01-01-2017,Swimming,8,8,8,24 
A5,14,Bhutan,2019,01-01-2017,Swimming,5,5,5,25 
A5,14,Bhutan,2019,01-01-2017,Swimming,5,5,5,25 
A5,14,Bhutan,2019,01-01-2017,Swimming,5,5,5,25 
A5,14,Bhutan,2019,01-01-2017,Swimming,5,5,5,25
```

1. List item

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not in the accumulator but here

```
if(x(0).toInt < 0)
```

`x` is of type `String` so `x(0)` refers to the first character of the string and `toInt` would convert it to corresponding code point value i.e. 45 for `-`.

There are many ways to do it, for example this would work:

```
val datVal = data.foreach { line =>
  "^-\\d+,".r.findFirstMatchIn(line).foreach(_ => badLines += 1)
}
```

P.S. Scala method `map` is not intended for side-effects and `foreach` should be used instead.

Comment: It's working .Thanks alot. But ,still I am splitting every row of record by "," , then why  first value is not getting extracted like -1 by (line.split(",").map{x=>x(0).toInt}

Comment: Because `x(0)` is the first character of every token, not the first token. Try `List("-4,13,India,2018,01-01-2017,Swimming,8,8,8,24",
         "A5,14,Bhutan,2019,01-01-2017,Swimming,5,5,5,25").foreach { line =>
      line.split(",").foreach(x => println(x(0)))
    }`  and this is printed `-
1
I
2
0
S
8
8
8
2
A
1
B
2
0
S
5
5
5
2`